# What is type is Site.objects.get_current() in django ; it returns <SIte: example.com>. I need to serialize it

Tags: python, django, celery, django-registration

I am trying to send an email with celery. I need to pass the `send_email` function the django site object, as obtained by `Site.objects.get_current()` (I am modifying django-registration-redux.)

I am unable to serialize the object or know what type it is to work with it.

Comment: Er, it's a Site object.

Comment: yes, ok... but how to i get the value it refers to , to serializer it... I am a bit lost .... sorry

Comment: Where in django-registration-redux did it tell you to serialise a Site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the [Django Site model](https://github.com/django/django/blob/967be82443b5640d61608a89897d8ce2bc44fa54/django/contrib/sites/models.py#L86)
The values are only `site.domain` and `site.name`
This model is used for when you're hosting multiple sites on one django platform. 
Use this to determine which site is accessed.